# Flexbox parent is taller than its children

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a small layout using flex and chunks form Bootstrap as well as a mini grid system but I'm having issues with situations where the children of that flexbox are not tall enough to actually fill it. In my case, if you go ahead and inspect the `.demo-install-components`, you can see that it has a higher height than its children. Surprisingly, if I add just another item `.install-component-individual` to the mix, it's fixed or if I remove the check icon `.installed-component-check`. To me, this smells very, very bad. It looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code (sorry for it being so long and on jsfiddle, wanted to provide everything I have):

[JSFiddle code.](https://jsfiddle.net/0r5sw6vq/)

What exactly am I missing here? I feel as if my knowledge of flexbox isn't complete.

Comment: if you remove `width:100%` from `#components-to-install-list` it will get fixed (don't know exactly why)

Comment: Or remove `flex-direction:column` from `.demo-install-components`. Then add `width:100%` to `.mass-actions`. (don't know exactly why either..)

Comment: @David Well, that's exactly my problem, ye? **Why does it do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Margin from `#components-to-install-list` ends up under your container.

By removing the `width` and `margin` from `#components-to-install-list` **(line 986-987 from CSS)**, the space underneath will disappear:

Comment: So, actually, the fix is to set `width` on `.demo-install-components`. Basically make sure that `width` is set to every parent. Alright...but why?

Comment: @DanielSmith you have a *lot* of nesting here which is a very bad practise. You are probably facing a kind of bug or complex calculation

Comment: @TemaniAfif There's no way to avoid nesting and somehwere, something is missing, `flexbox` isn't stupid, it does what it tells you and was hoping someone could tell me why it behaves like this.

Comment: @DanielSmith it's not flexbox who is doing the job but your browser that try to follow the flexbox specification and implement it. In some cases you may have complex or unexpected behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is to say, this isn't normal behavior and can be expected to not happen again under regular circumstances?